# findIndex return -1, but it should return 0

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(books[0]._id);
console.log(user.bookRecomendations);
const index = user.bookRecomendations.findIndex( x => x.bookId === books[0]._id);
console.log(index);
```

It return in console:

```
5b0685e238e2e50ba4c10d49

[{"bookId":"5b0685e238e2e50ba4c10d49","rating":900},{"bookId":"5b0949a3b7c9170be08aa6b5","rating":900},{"bookId":"5b0708dbf1079d0dfa98489b","rating":900},{"bookId":"5b0948947c110b0ba9069327","rating":1600}]

-1
```

as user.bookRecomendations[0].bookId have the same value as book[0]._id it should return 0, but still it do not, and shows -1 as it was no match. Any suggestions how to fix it and get index of user.bookRecomendations with bookId equal to books[0]._id?

EDIT:

```
console.log('['+books[0]._id+']');
console.log('['+user.bookRecomendations[0].bookId+']’);
console.log(books[0]._id===user.bookRecomendations[0].bookId);
```

returns:

```
[5b0685e238e2e50ba4c10d49]
[5b0685e238e2e50ba4c10d49]
false
```

Comment: Not reproducible for me. The `findIndex` function correctly returns `0` for me. Try creating a fiddle/plunker or SO snippet.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: It returns 0. Create a jsfiddle and recreate this problem.

Comment: Make sure `books[0]._id` does not contain a trailing space or newline; they are not visible in the output of `console.log()` as you used it. Post the output of `console.log('['+books[0]._id+']');`

Comment: @31piy amen to that. Just on my first cup of morning coffeee...ooops

Comment: @31piy a hex number.

Comment: console.log('['+books[0]._id+']’) returns [5b0685e238e2e50ba4c10d49]

Comment: @charlietfl has a point - `===` requires that both sides are of the same type, whereas `==` does some more lenient and implicit conversion.

Comment: You may check books[0]._id===user.bookRecomendations[0].bookId and see whether that is an equality

Comment: @mrblewog -- though it is a valid hex sequence, hex numbers in JavaScript are defined by a `0x` at the beginning. Plus, `0x5b0685e238e2e50ba4c10d49` results in `2.817102169646556e+28` on my console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem was with type, both books[0]._id and user.bookRecomendations[0].bookId were objects. 
So comparing

```
books[0]._id.toString() === user.bookRecomendations[0].bookId.toString()
```

works perfectly